# local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want it to count every time someone says hi or hey, but I cant set the variable to 0.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    ctx.content = ctx.content.lower()
    if "hi" in ctx.content:
        count = count + 1
    if "hey" in ctx.content:
        count = count + 1
    if ctx.content == "!count":
        print("yes")
        await ctx.channel.send(count)
```

Comment: You do `count = count + 1` in your `if` statements but never declared/initialized a `count`.

Comment: Is your `count` initialized somewhere in code that you haven't shown? If so, you may need a `nonlocal count` in the `on_message` function.

Comment: I don't know how [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#context) is passed around, but unless something fancy happens with it, you _may_ be able to store your count there, so it persists. For example, `ctx._count = 0` just outside your conditionals. Then you should be able to do `ctx._count += 1` and `ctx.channel.send(ctx._count)`.

Comment: The alternative is declaring count outside the function, `count = 0`, and then using `global count` inside the function before the conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `count` at the start before you start counting

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `count` is defined after the calls to it. Try moving that line above the if blocks:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    count = 0
    # -- snip --
```

(FYI, this code will not persist the count, e.g. it will be reset every time the script reboots.)

Comment: The first example doesn't quite work since you initialize `count` outside the scope of `on_message`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice fixed, my bad.